# How to rename a project in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, rename

We tried to rename a project in Xcode 7 using the [standard instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/RenamingaProject/RenamingaProject.html) but it didn't work.   After the rename the build option was greyed out.  Seems there are additional steps required but I haven't found a list which is up to date as of v7.  How can you do the rename in v7?

Comment: These steps works for me.  you might want to recheck?

Comment: "We tried to rename a project" Best approach: Don't. There's no need, since the project name is not something that ever faces the user or Apple.

Comment: Hi @Marcus Leon , 
Please look at it once below link 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRnVjtNLLLk

Answer (score 0):

If the run button is gray, you can edit the scheme. For an easy way you can click product -> manage scheme. Delete the current scheme and then click autocreate scheme now on the top-right corner.

Answer (score 0):

Standard instructions or just softly double tap on project name which is usually on left side and just write the new name. It will pop up a new screen as show in the link shared by you and thats it. Can't really guess why it doesn't work for you as I have just tried a minute back on mine and its v7.